# Install app restriction on some part of work profile

Tags: android, restriction, device-policy-manager, usermanager, android-work-profile

I want to use DISALLOW_INSTALL_APPS in UserManager on my work profile. But I want install and update applications that exits in my app store, but don't let to install other app stores out of my app. How should do it?
It means that I want to update and install apps from my application on work profile and the other part of work profile has restrictions.